# ListContourPlot

Tags: plotting, list-manipulation

I am having some issue with ListContourPlot. When I define the following Array:

```
B = {{1, 1, 1, 1, 1, 1, 1, 1, 1, 1}, {1, 1, 1, 1, 1, 1, 1, 1, 1, 1}, 
{1, 1, 1, 1, 1, 1, 1, 1, 1, 1}, {1, 1, 1, 1, 1, 1, 1, 1, 1, 1}, 
{1, 1, 1, 1, 1, 1, 1, 1, 1, 1}, {1, 1, 1, 1, 1, 1, 0.97561`, 
0.97959`, 0.98889`, 0.97778`}, {1, 1, 1, 1, 1, 0.9875`, 0.9798`, 
0.96552`, 0.97895`, 1}, {1, 1, 0.95455`, 1, 0.94667`, 0.96591`, 1, 
0.97143`, 0.96721`, 0.92593`}, {1, 0.98148`, 0.98485`, 0.975`, 
0.93269`, 0.94059`, 0.94776`, 0.92053`, 0.85976`, 0.9058`}, {1, 1, 
0.97183`, 0.8972`, 0.89167`, 0.86667`, 0.86429`, 0.85083`, 
0.81006`, 0.84422`}}
```

And then try to do a ListContourPlot of it, with the result being:

[image]

The top RHS of the graph should be shaded darkest, as these numbers here are the lowest, however, at the moment as you can see they are shaded as white (indicating that the numbers here are high).

Does anyone know what I am doing wrong here? And, how can I make the shading behave as I expect it to?

Best,

Ben

Comment: `ListContourPlot[B, PlotLegends -> Automatic, PlotRange -> Full, Contours -> 20]`

Answer (score 6):

*Mathematica* clips these regions because it tries to make a clever decision about what is *interesting* for you. You can force the coloring of those parts by using

```
ListContourPlot[B, ClippingStyle -> Automatic]
```

[image: Mathematica graphics]

Comment: many thanks, that really helps.